# Why are pointers not located on a stack?

Tags: c, pointers

```
void main(){
    int i,k;
    char* p;
    int j;
    printf("address of i is %d \naddress of k is %d \naddress of p is %p\naddress of j is %d", &i,&k,&p,&j);

}
```

when I tried the above code, the address of j is 4 units below k. But the address of p is no where near. Since a pointer is an integer variable that could store 4 bytes of data, why isn't it allocated on the stack like the other three variables?

Comment: Some formal notes:
- main() should return int
- When using printf(), always make sure to put '\n' at the end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should post the output you're getting.  I suspect that you're getting a bit confused because most of the addresses you're printing are being displayed in decimal (using %d) while `p` is being displayed in hex (using %p).

Answer (score 13):

Use `%p` to print all the addresses.

Spoiler: It **is** on the stack.

Comment: Note that you *must* cast each argument for %p to `(void *)`. All the code samples so far invoke _undefined behavior_ because the format specifier does not match the argument type. While it might not make much difference, bullet-proof code uses `#include <stdio.h>`, `int main (void)` and `printf ("%p\n", (void *)&p);` etc.

Answer (score 6):

I just tried your code on my computer (running Ubuntu 9.04) and got the following:

```
address of i is 0xbf96fe30
address of k is 0xbf96fe2c
address of p is 0xbf96fe28
address of j is 0xbf96fe24
```

after changing the code somewhat:

```
void main(){
    int i,k;
    char* p;
    int j;
    printf("address of i is %p \naddress of k is %p \naddress of p is %p\naddress of j is %p\n", &i,&k,&p,&j);

}
```

Since all you're printf() are addresses you should use %p instead of %d. Maybe you misinterpreted your results?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `%d` `printf()` specifier you get an address printed as decimal number and when you use `%p` specifier you get it printed as hexadecimal number. It just happened that the hexadecimal number contains no letters and you misinterpret it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end a pointer is a variable.As far as the linux architecture is concerned,it is very clear that

> All those variables  whose memory is localized to a function will remain on the stack.<

There is no reason why for the above case the pointers should not be on the stack.Its a case of misinterpreting the ouput and **ignoring the warning from gcc.Its a case with beginners that they ignore gcc warnings as harmless.There are cases when they are equivalent to a compiler error**

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but tell you that your program is one of those that "should be indented six feet and covered with dirt." (google for who said it when and why:-)
It is a prime example of sloppyness for the following reasons, most of which are causing undefined behavior:

- Uses printf without including stdio.h
- Uses void main
- Uses %d for addresses
- Uses %p with something other than a ptr-to-void

Properly written it looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i, k;
    char *p;
    int j;

    printf ("address of i is %p\n", (void *)&i);
    printf ("address of k is %p\n", (void *)&k);
    printf ("address of p is %p\n", (void *)&p);
    printf ("address of j is %p\n", (void *)&j);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pointers may or may not be located on the stack as they are also some sort of variables. Note that they are some **not very big** variables. If the CPU/MCU has lots of registers and the compiler optimizes well, you may not see a pointer on the stack, it may very well spend its whole lifetime in registers.

Comment: In the OPs case the compiler cannot optimize the pointer variable away, as the code expects to get the memory address of the variable (&p), which is not valid for a register.

Comment: @Frank: I was referring the question (the title itself), not the given code snippet...

Comment: Is it a sin to elaborate on questions :-)

Comment: @Malkocoglu: No it is not, but then you should somehow make clear, that your answer doesn't reference the OPs actual question. You should also consider, that your answer might lead the OP into a false direction when looking for a solution to his problem.